# Sass source map support on chrome isn't working

Tags: css, linux, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass

Before start, I double check on StackExchange and I didn't find any other site that will fit this question. If I missed, excuses.

I followed [this](http://fonicmonkey.net/2013/03/25/native-sass-scss-source-map-support-in-chrome-and-rails/) guide, to enable chrome that support with source maps sass, but I can't make it work.

The funny part is that I followed another guide, to enable support for Firefox, and is working.

The part that both have in common is setting up the `config.sass.debug_info = true` in rails.

So, I think that the problem isn't on rails but in chrome, but I'm not sure.

This is my setup:

- rails 3.2.8
- Ubuntu
- Chrome 27.0.1453.110

**update** - It seems like the problem is with Chrome 27.x series. If that is the case, this question turns to be a waiting for fix from chrome developers. So I'll investigate a bit more, if I can confirm, I'll close this question. Thanks for your time.

**update** - So it seems to be true, this is an issue of google chrome, thanks to all for your help

Comment: So your question is about Sass source maps and not directly about Sass (which browsers do not natively support)?

Comment: Well, yes. I need help making chrome show me sass instead of the compiled css.

Comment: I noticed this too and was going to file a bug, but wasn't sure if it was down to my machine... I guess not.

Comment: Someone's looked a little more in depth to the problem and filed a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=247761&q=sass%20source%20map&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following the tutorial in [this link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/developing-with-sass-and-chrome-devtools/). I just set this up this morning and it's working fine for me.

This will let you inspect an element and then find what the corresponding SCSS declaration is.

Comment: Looks like ultimate problem was my sass version :S

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Chrome developer tools recently changed what version of source maps it supports.  The article you mention details how to set up an older style of CSS source maps.  However, Chrome now supports [version 3 source maps](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit#heading=h.75yo6yoyk7x5).  The new source maps puts the mapping in a separate *.css.map file instead of inline in the compiled CSS file.  The benefits of the new format is that it is much smaller and does not break styles for older Internet Explorers.  The [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/developing-with-sass-and-chrome-devtools/) that @justin-smith provided should point you in the right direction.  However, from my findings, even though the pre-released version 3.3 of the SASS gem knows how to generate the .map files, there still needs to be support from the sass-rails gem to correctly serve these files from the Rails asset pipeline.  I created a [repo](https://github.com/gerryster/rails4-v3-sourcemaps) in order to figure out the current state of support for v3 sass source maps in Rails.  There may be a way to short circuit the asset pipeline and have the sass gem precompile files and put them in a directory which comes early in the asset path.  However, I have not figured out how to to this.

Comment: We need something similar to [this gist for CoffeeScript](https://gist.github.com/naan/5096056) but that works for Sass. Anyone willing to dig into the sass source to get that to work?

Comment: I wrote simmilar [gem](https://github.com/vhyza/sass-rails-source-maps) to [coffee-rails-source-maps](https://github.com/markbates/coffee-rails-source-maps) which is base on mentioned gist. You can read more at [blog post](http://blog.vhyza.eu/blog/2013/09/22/debugging-rails-4-coffeescript-and-sass-source-files-in-google-chrome/)

Answer (score 2):

I just had problem getting SASS source maps getting to work on my host.... I had completely no idea what could be the solution because the map-file was generated, the sourceMappingURL-tag was present and everything was fine, Chrome was configured and I even used the canary-version..... but then I got it: 
I used a development Webserver with a self signed SSL-certificate which I need to test my authentication etc.. When I switched to plain HTTP without encryption my sourcemaps got working instantly.

Answer (score 1):

As @gerryster said, Chrome now supports `source maps proposal v 3`. I wrote blog post about [Debugging Rails 4 CoffeeScript and Sass source files in Google Chrome](http://blog.vhyza.eu/blog/2013/09/22/debugging-rails-4-coffeescript-and-sass-source-files-in-google-chrome/).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has tried everything and can't get css source maps to work, make sure the source map is actually accessible via URL. In my case, rewrite rules were not exposing the source map. Once I changed that, it worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else ends up here after struggling to make Chrome work with Sass, you need to run a different command to generate source maps via command line: `sass --watch --sourcemap sass/styles.scss:styles.css` instead of `--debug-info`. The newer versions of Chrome now support source maps instead of the in-css debug info.
More info: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/tips-and-tricks#debugging-sass

Comment: I've actually decided to use `sass --watch --sourcemap --debug-in sass/screen.scss:screen.css` because the resulting css & source map allow me to use FireSass and Chrome for debugging.

Comment: --sourcemap is now deprecated and also requires an option, --sourcemap=inline for example.  Options are auto (the default), file, inline, or none.